# How can i make this text follow this circle path?

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, parent, text-object, path

The point where im trying to get is making the text orbit the sphere, i already tried to use the follow path but guess im doing something wrong, because the animation cames pretty broken once i start playing.

here you can see what I want to do and what is happening in the video below:

https://youtu.be/AYrB4X8kDXU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use the Curve Deform to get the text bent around the curve and then add keyframes to rotate the curve itself. Rather than messing with the offset or whatever, that seems like a big headache between a Curve Deform, Follow Path constrain all rolled into one.

Curve Deform:
[image]

Then just set the curve rotation to 0 on frame 1 and 360 on one frame past the last frame and it will loop perfectly.

[image]